# Which App handles incoming calls?

Tags: android, phone-call, android-phone-call

On incoming calls only a phone number or contact name is displayed. I want to see more information about the contact, for example company or my notes.

Therefore I want to extend the app which is launched on incoming calls. What is the name of this app in LineageOS 14.1 (Android 7.1.2) and where can i find the code to load it with Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

We couldn't answer this.  All of those apps are overridable by the OEMs.  You can't assume that a particular version of Android will have a particular app.  Nor can you assume it will be open source so you could load it into android studio-  it might be, but it could just as easily be a custom closed source app by the OEM.

Comment: or Android Open Source Project?